# Job opportunities

Tags: video-games, film-sound-design, job-opportunities

Does anyone know the difference in job opportunities between video game sound design and film sound design. Which one has more opportunities to get a job, know from experience? Is the pay any different?

Answer (score 1):

As an active job seeker, I've seen more game audio jobs than film jobs. But, lately, there have been more internships in audio post as well as entry level positions as a runner in an audio post facility.  But, I just started looking so my answer may not be all that accurate.